# How to send an email from a windows machine by using remote SMTP server (configured to run on localhost on Linux environment)?

Tags: linux, smtp, localhost, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I have an application running on Windows machine. the application related alerts are to be e-mailed to administrator,for which an e-mail needs to be sent by Java program.  The SMTP server is configured on a remote  Linux machine in network.

The Java Mail program works fine and sends out an email, when run on the Linux machine. However if the same program is run on Windows it fails to connect to the SMTP server.

Note:

1. Ping to the Linux Machine (having SMTP server) is successful from Remote windows server.
2. Telnet < SMTP server hostname >   25  fails from remote machine as well from the machine where SMTP is running
3. Telnet localhost  25 is sucessful from SMTP server (Linux server).

The email by Java program is sucessfull, if run on SMTP server when hostname is specified as localhost.It fails if you give actual hostname.

/etc/hosts file on SMTP server lists 127.0.0.1 localhost.

How can i use the SMTP server to send an email from remote Windows machine?

I can paste the errors coming up on windows machine but the problem is not with the program; its the way the SMTP server is configured. I am new to SMTP so feel free to correct me if  i am wrong.

The objective is to send a java e-mail from remote windows machine using the SMTP server on the Linux machine.

**Adding the Output of netstat -ant|grep :25 as requested in the comment below:**

```
[root@XXXXXXXXXXX]# netstat -ant | grep :25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.207.70.71:1521    ::ffff:10.207.70.71:25481   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.207.70.71:25481   ::ffff:10.207.70.71:1521    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.207.70.71:25202   ::ffff:10.207.70.71:3001    TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.207.70.71:25127   ::ffff:10.207.70.71:3001    TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.207.70.71:25289   ::ffff:10.207.70.71:3001    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ::1:51432                   ::1:25580                   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ::1:25580                   ::1:51432                   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.207.70.71:25233   ::ffff:10.207.70.71:3001    TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.207.70.71:3001    ::ffff:10.207.70.71:25289   ESTABLISHED
[root@XXXXXXXXXXX]#
```

Comment: Sounds like that smtp server is not configured to bind to a network interface.

Comment: a) what is reported by `nestat -ant | grep :25` (list of IP addresses your MTA/SMTP server listens on) b) name MTA/SMTP server you use

Comment: @Andrzej A.Filip  -  I have added the output of netstat command above. Iam trying to configure the hmailserver as MTA but not sure if its configured correctly.

Comment: Your smtp server accepts SMTP connections only on 127.0.0.1:25, it does not allow smtp connections from outside/internet.  Name SMTP/MTA server software you use - configuration fixes are server specific. Usually you get server software name in SMTP greeting - see `telnet 127.0.0.1 25`.

Comment: @Andrzej  I think its Postfix:    [root@]# telnet 127.0.0.1 25 
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to 127.0.0.1.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    220 XXXXXXXX383.localdomain ESMTP Postfix

Comment: most probably is the firewall (iptables or firewalld) preventing connections to local port 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Postfix: Accepting SMTP connections on ALL IP interrfaces

Your SMTP server (postfix) accepts incoming SMTP connection only on loopback interface(s)
 [IPv4=127.0.0.1 and IPv6=::1].

Make your postfix listen on all available IP interfaces -> in `main.cf` configuration file restore default setting `inet_interfaces = all`

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces

---

**Why "loopback only" configuration is used?**

Limiting SMTP server to accept only local SMTP connections is pretty common default configuration on "workstations". It allows sending emails (e.g. system warnings/notifications) without accepting any incoming spam.

Comment: thanks, That did work!. However i have a question, does making the option to all have any security concern ? Is it possible that only  one remote windows server is able to relay the emails and others in the network cannot ?

Comment: You may use Linux firewall (iptables) to accept incoming SMTP connections only on loopback interface and from specific IP address on other IP interfaces.  Do you want to accept incoming emails from "whole Internet"?